# Should I ask the seller of a house for a price reduction given a recession is almost certain?

Tags: mortgage, economics, ireland, house-sale, covid-19

I've gone sale agreed (**note**: "sale agreed" means the sale has been agreed in principle - no contracts have been signed, no non-refundable deposits have been made etc.) on a house. The market I'm currently in was extremely competitive, houses were all generally going for significantly more than their asking price, as mine did.

I have nearly everything ready - loan arranged, survey of the house completed, solicitor ready to sign everything.

Now with Covid, a recession is more than likely coming our way.

Furthermore, with lock-downs in place - the seller is extremely unlikely to find an alternative buyer in the near future (it's an executor sale if that makes any difference).

I was thinking of trying to put some pressure onto the seller to lower the agreed price.

While I don't want to lose the house (and the money we have spent so far on legal etc.), I would also like to take advantage of potentially lower mortgage repayments.

Is it a bad idea to put this to the estate agent and be forthright about exactly why I'm asking to lower the price? Is there a "reasonable" amount to lower the purchase price by?

**Edit**

My intention here isn't to "screw" the seller as several commentators assume that I am trying to do.

At the end of the day, I'm a first time buyer who has effectively agreed to buy a house at "peak" economic health. Within a couple of weeks of this agreement, economic impacts of covid-19 were already being felt and the short / medium term prospects are not good.

At the end of this year, if covid hasn't wreaked enough havoc, there is a very real risk that Brexit could have an extremely negative impact on my country.

So while the honorable thing to do might be to commit to the agreed purchase price, this might be an extremely unwise decision from a personal finance point of view.

"Why don't you just pull out of the sale then?"

I could do that, that leaves the seller in a very bad position as well - it will be extremely unlikely they will be able to find another buyer in the short / medium term - so giving them an opportunity to consider my concerns might be better than simply walking away.

**Outcome Edit**

The bank valued the property about 6% lower than the agreed purchase price (mostly due to Covid). This effectively meant that the maximum amount the bank would lend was 6% less than what we had originally sought. We weren't willing to try and pay a larger deposit to fill the gap and informed the seller + estate agent (providing the banks valuation of the property). The seller agreed almost immediately to the reduction and we closed within a couple of weeks thereafter.

Comment: Who says a recession is certain?

Comment: perhaps not certain, but there is a lot of noise being made about it

Comment: If you did this and I was the seller I would give you a firm no. If you reneged on the agreed upon deal I would take your earnest money and refuse to deal with you again regardless of how difficult it might be to find another buyer.

Comment: what's earnest money?

Comment: to clarify - it's "sale agreed", we haven't signed anything so there's no deposit to lose.

Comment: Take care with this. In some countries/states, a verbal agreement is a contract. Harder to prove in court, but still a legally binding contract.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely.  ASAP.  Least, the seller needs to know of your shifting mindframe on the price, so they can act accordingly.

Comment: For sure. At this stage of negotiations - nothing is legal until something is signed

Comment: At the very least you will seriously annoy the seller. A simple way to check if this is OK - imagine that good economic news had been announced and the seller came to you and said "because prices are going to go up I want more money than we agreed". Would you think that was OK?

Comment: @PeteB. We're already in one...

Comment: Country tag is important for this sort of question.  Also to Pete - in most places a recession is already fact...  (Edited in based on another comment you made.)

Comment: @DJClayworth that's business, why wouldn't you raise the price if conditions change, sucks if you are on the losing end but if there is no contract that's life

Comment: If you don't care about personal qualities like honesty, decency, and trustworthiness, then sure, go ahead and screw the guy,

Comment: @user1723699 and Michael Kay I don't understand why you think I'm trying to "screw" the seller - the fact is the economic circumstances have drastically changed since agreeing to purchase the house. I think committing to the original circumstances without any consideration to the current and future prospects would be extremely unwise

Comment: Something to consider: some, but not all, of the house price hike in the UK is (depending on Locale) due to Property Investment from Russia, America, or Arabic countries such as Saudi Arabia.  Funnily enough, Brexit is *very unlikely* to change that - and if Brexit weakens the Pound, then them spending the same amount of *their* money would make UK house prices **go up**, not down.

Comment: @SiHa OP says *"I'm a first time buyer"* - no one is buying from them (presumably currently renting?)

Comment: @Chronocidal Ireland is not in the UK and does not suffer from the issues you mentioned. A poor Brexit outcome in terms of trading with the EU will have dire consequences on Ireland as it's one of our main trading partners. House prices are high due to low supply of houses on the market.

Comment: Think in the perspective of seller. He would have been very happy to have found a buyer at a good price. COVID is not the fault of the seller. It is not something he hided from you. It is not something a problem in his house which you found and will incur significant costs for you to repair. You are trying to blame the seller for something he does not have control to. Even tacit agreement is a agreement. If a company offers you an employment and suddenly asking you for a lower salary, will you agree ? Word given is word given.

Comment: @VenkataramanR If you agree in principle to buy stock for €100 a share from me in a week, then a week has passed and that stock is now worth €80 - are you still going to buy them for €100 each from me?

Comment: @TomSelleck, personally, I would still buy at the agreed price.

Comment: This does not seem to me about personal finaces rather then ethics. "Should I ..." is generally a bad start for any question on stackoverflow. We can´t make a decision for you nor do we have to live with it.

Comment: @TomSelleck Sorry, your mentioning of Brexit made me assume that you meant Northern Ireland, or the Island of Ireland, not the Republic of Ireland.  (Also, your stock / shares example?  That's basically how [Futures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-stock_futures) work, and you *would* have to pay)

Comment: A recession will come,  . It will be followed by an upturn. This will be followed by recession. ... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_cycle .

Comment: @SimonArsenault Good point. Would OP back-out of the deal in my jurisdiction, he'd be out 10% of the agreed sum for damages by default. I don't know what their law states, but this is a non-simple matter.

Comment: You claim in your edit that, you're not trying to screw them, but then state, "...there is a very real risk that Brexit could have an extremely negative impact on my country." You knew this well in advance of the agreement and trying to use it as a bargaining chip now makes it seem as though you're not interested in acting in good faith, but simply appearing to cover your ill intent.

Comment: @GlenPierce Yes I did know about Brexit long before the agreement... not the global pandemic sweeping the planet however. This is probably the most important financial decision I'll ever have to make - there are no "bargaining chips" or ill intent, you make it out as I set out to buy a house with the intent of ripping someone off. Believe it or not, I need to buy somewhere to live and pay for it for the rest of my life. I think looking into the future and incorporating it into my current decisions is better than blindly going forward.

Comment: @TomSelleck A verbal agreement is still a contract. Keep in mind the seller could sue you for changing or cancelling the deal. The lawsuit could be for difference of what you agreed to pay versus what he gets from a different buyer (if lower) plus some arbitrary amount for troubles & interests. You're the only one able to judge if it's worth it or not to go full-Vader (http://www.quickmeme.com/img/e1/e1bb2397fdfdaf5ab49a377cb9a823624b2a21195ab35f7bb9a2f5eb33c60931.jpg).

Comment: @SimonArsenault Not in my locality - nothing is legal until something has been signed

Comment: IANAL, but in Ireland verbal contracts seem to be valid under some circumstances: https://businessandlegal.ie/tag/oral-contract 

Whether it applies to you or not is unknown to me. You might want to consult a lawyer before doing anything.

Comment: Based on my experience in Ireland under very different market conditions (dot com. boom), if I really wanted the property I wouldn't risk it.  The real estate market in Ireland is fraught with gazumping, and poor market conditions will only increase the incidence of that.

Comment: If tonight, someone invents a cure and economies come roaring back, and the seller then tells you he's increasing the price, what would you do?

Comment: @Matt I imagine you would deal with it, what else?.  I also imagine such a scenario would leave the price after similar to the price before.  Why would the price increase over the pre covid price, that makes no sense whatsoever.  Furthermore even if a cure was released today, there would still be profound economic damage to unravel, nobody's economy is going to come roaring back

Comment: I believe this is called "gazundering".

Comment: When verbal contracts are legal, contracts involving real estate are widely specifically required in writing by statute. Even if I said "I'll give you a trillion dollars for the house" and you said "yes", you wouldn't have a single cause of action at all when I laugh at your request for the keys. @SimonArsenault

Comment: quite a narrow perspective from some commentors here. to put the question in other terms: "if i agreed in principle to buy x for a certain price but am not yet legally obliged to go ahead with the purchase, and the market value of that x has now decreased significantly, should i still go ahead with the purchase?" - that's all that's being asked here so not sure why it's so controversial. Either you are taking the brunt of the value reduction by buying at the original price or the current owner is taking the brunt by lowering the price now or pulling out...

Comment: Other things to consider is the bank may not still be happy with the valuation from the original survey and may not be happy with the mortgage LTV that would leave them with, so might just be easier to check with them whether they want it re-valued then it might be slightly easier to manage the seller. Another consideration for you might be if you're a first time buyer are you currently wasting more money renting than you would be saving by having your own property, or have you already spent more on this property than you would save by pulling out and buying a different property

Comment: And also if you're a first time buyer with a 95% mortgage you might want to consider the risk of becoming an instant mortgage prisoner not being able to remortgage when your first deal runs out

Comment: Oh and one more thing to consider is whether mortgage lenders are tightening their lending conditions now and whether it would be harder for you to get another mortgage deal in a few months time i.e. whether you're missing your chance to get on the property ladder by not going ahead with this one

Comment: How at risk are you for getting laid off? If you get laid off, how at risk is your payments? If you are talking about "maybes" vs "most likelies" that should impact your decision to sign a 30 year contract.

Comment: The central bank for Ireland just put out their forecast today. It looks pretty dire where ever you happen to be in Ireland. 8.3% hit to GDP and unemployment to 25%. Projections of course. But do you really begrudge someone taking a second thought on the price given that background?
https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/news/irish-2020-gdp-may-fall-231111008.html

Comment: You were obviously ready to purchase until circumstances caused you to fear you would be overpaying in a declining market.  Rather than lower your price, the honorable thing to do would be to explain this to the seller and walk.

Let the seller come back with a counter offer, should they choose that route, and you decide if it's "reasonable", rather than having to play the insulting game of you driving the price down on them, appearing to take advantage of the situation.

Comment: @SimonArsenault Most contracts can be concluded verbally, but a contract for the sale of property is usually an exception to that rule and has to be in writing.

Comment: Talk to your lawyer about this! You hired a lawyer specializing in real estate, right? They know the area, they know the market, and they might have experience with that particular real estate agent and that particular seller. And obviously they know the local law. I can't believe nobody has said this before.

Comment: @SimonArsenault contracts on something as important as real estate must be in writing. No contract can oblige you to sign a future contract not yet finalized, that  contradicts the very nature of contract law.

Comment: @Joooeey in some countries you normally use a realtor not a lawyer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the OP mentioned a solicitor (that's a lawyer according to my dictionary). Based on that statement I assumed he had hired a lawyer. Could be the broker's or the seller's lawyer though, who knows.

Comment: @Joooeey In the UK (and I guess Ireland will be fairly similar), this is not a legal issue. If you hire a lawyer they will simply advise you that you don't have a legally binding contract yet, and that you need to make your own decision. A lawyer can't tell you whether you should or shouldn't make an investment; it is [illegal](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/8/section/19) for a lawyer to give [investment advice](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/8/schedule/2) without FCA authorisation (which the vast majority will not have).

Comment: @TomSelleck did you hire a lawyer to represent you in this transaction?

Comment: @TomSelleck, just curious. What did you decide to do?

Comment: @PeterG Everything has been put on hold due to Covid restrictions

Comment: WRT your edit, it's a year later and while I don't know about Ireland, hereabouts there's no recession and house prices continue to climb.

Answer (score 39):

You could ask, but you risk the seller deciding to just cancel and put the property back on the market once restrictions lift, shutting you out. Depending on the exact neighborhood and local market, there is no guarantee that a recession will even affect the chosen neighborhood. You described it as a very competitive, presumably it will still be a desirable neighborhood even in a recession and you didn't mention how vulnerable the local economy is to a recession.

Comment: Local economy is Ireland so if Brexit negotiations go south - pretty vulnerable...

Comment: You have to consider not just Ireland as a whole, but the specific area. Recession effects aren't evenly distributed.

Comment: @TomSelleck, "Ireland" isn't your local economy.  Your local economy is the city within Ireland, or perhaps the section of the city.  As an example, the last time a housing bubble burst in the US, the estimated value of my house went *up* 10%, despite overall housing prices in the city (and country) falling.

Comment: The seller could do that, and then risk that they end up having to sell it for a much lower price.  This is hardly even speculation, it is highly highly likely that house prices are going to fall and not just a little.

Comment: @eps Or, they just check with other buyers as to whether their offer is still valid:  If Tom was offering €XY7,500, he now wants to pay €XY2,500, but the next best offer was €XY5,000, then the Seller may decide to drop their price by €2,500 instead of €5,000.  This isn't only a **2**-player game

Comment: @Mark what local economy is this that went up 10% (i presume during the great recession)? In general, i prefer to measure value using closed transaction prices rather than estimates.

Comment: @WittyID, a neighborhood reasonably close to a newly-expanded university campus.  Sudden influx of students looking for off-campus housing = rising home prices.

Comment: @Mark I understand there are many such causal variables. I was asking for something I could anchor/verify with hard data rather than an anecdote. A neighborhood name, township or zip-code would suffice.

Answer (score 23):

With the caveat that I'm assuming your verbal agreement isn't legally binding ([AIG says it isn't](https://www.aig.ie/our-blog/what-happens-after-house-sale-agreed)), I would pull out of the deal completely if I were in your shoes. By negotiating, you're essentially trying to price an unprecedented global financial/economic meltdown. What is the right haircut to the existing price? 5%? 10%? 50%? Are you looking for a reduction to make you feel better, or attempting to re-price the house accurately. Unless there was a reason why you absolutely had to move, I would walk away from the deal and stay put until things cleared.

A risk you didn't mention is after buying this house and having to start mortgage payments, when will you be able to move in given lockdowns? I have friends sitting on two mortgages who can't sell their existing homes, or work on/move into the new one given lockdowns in our city. They would probably love to rewind the clock and abandon their deposit.

I would ignore everyone here talking about honor and screwing people. The fact is you are not in a legally binding contract, and even those (of every financial magnitude) are being challenged and re-negotiated globally because of the financial ruin associated with honoring **binding** terms that did not envision circumstances like we're in today (your case is non-binding). Everything is significantly different enough from even 2 weeks ago, or even last week (depending on where you live), that if I were selling a house in this environment, I would be surprised if the buyer went through with it.

Comment: This is definitely the only advice the OP should listen to. There is nothing dishonourable in abandoning the purchase. Yes, it will be frustrating for the seller, but they will (or should) appreciate that they never had a binding contract. Effectively you are in the negotiations stage until the contract is signed, and either party is free to back away. Buying a property right now, particularly at a price you agreed before the financial crash, would be an act of financial irresponsibility.

Answer (score 19):

If you've already signed a contract, it's too late. Well, barring legal shenanigans.

If you haven't signed a contract, then sure, you can ask. That's how negotiations work. The buyer comes up with reasons why he should pay less, the seller gives reasons why he should pay more.

I wouldn't expect asking for a lower price to derail the sale. The seller could say no, I don't think there will be a recession, or I don't think this area will be affected by it, or it doesn't matter if there is or not because I can't afford to sell for any less than this, or whatever. Then you have to decide whether to pay a higher price or you call off the sale. If you're really rude and obnoxious about it I suppose a seller might decide that they don't want to deal with you and call it off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Nothing signed yet, still going through the motions. I had no intention of going hardball / threatening to walk away from negotiations - I fully intended on saying how I was feeling given the current climate - but what I didn't know is if that it's a valid reason to ask for a negotiation on the price

Comment: There's really no such thing as an invalid reason to ask for a lower price. "I'm concerned about the long term value." "I can't afford that price." "I think aliens will invade." It doesn't matter. (Well, maybe some anti-discrimination laws would apply to you if you said you are afraid that black people are moving into this neighborhood or some such.) Even if the seller thinks the reason is not applicable or plain stupid, too bad.

Comment: Are you trying to say that by signing an offer on a house the seller can sue someone and compel them to complete the deal at that price?!?

Comment: @trognanders Umm, I'm not sure. I'm not a lawyer. The question would be whether, if the seller then signs the offer, it is at that point a legally binding contract. Offers often have "escape clauses", like saying that it is contingent on an inspection, buyer being able to obtain financing, etc. Arguably those are superfluous if it is NOT a binding contract. If you could just say "forget it" for any reason, why would you need to write in reasons? But I'd check with a lawyer or a realtor before I made assumptions. I'll gladly yield here to someone who actually knows.

Comment: @trognanders In the UK, anything leading up to the sale contract is non-binding. That's because property sales, unlike most other contracts, have specific rules attaching to them. Once the contract is signed, if one party fails to complete then the options are: (1) rescind the contract and claim damages and/or (in the buyer's case) forfeit the deposit, or (2) apply to court for specific performance (i.e. force the sale) which although an equitable remedy, will nearly always be granted because property is unique and damages don't suffice. I suspect Ireland isn't too dissimilar to the UK.

Comment: @JBentley By sale contract are you referring to something similar to the mountain of paperwork we refer to as "closing" in the US?

Comment: @trognanders I'm not sure, I am unfamiliar with the US system. In the UK we do "searches" and "enquiries" after an offer is made and accepted. They check the background of the property, the title, and other similar matters to ensure that everything is ok. Once all that is done and both sides are happy to proceed we "exchange contracts" which is the legally-binding part and also the point at which the buyer pays a 10% deposit. Then there usually a delay of a week or a few weeks until "completion" when the remaining money is paid and keys are handed over. Little paperwork is done in that period.

Comment: @JBentley That is actually quite different from the US I think. When we bought a house a (small) deposit amount, like $1000, was included in the offer to the seller. When they accepted it, the deposit was paid. After that there was a walk away for any reason inspection period, also negotiated, basically the searches and inquiries. The actual closing happens a few weeks after the inspection period, the buyer brings money and the seller brings a deed... the serious part all happens at once. It may be possible to sue to force the sale before closing, but afaik it is at least not common practice.

Comment: @JBentley With 10% of the purchase price on the line during the last part, someone would need a lot of motivation to walk away!

Answer (score 12):

My wife and I run a real estate brokerage in Florida. The transaction process is different here but principles are similar. I think there's a good chance the deal will fall apart if you try to renegotiate the price at this stage.

Buyers and sellers in residential real estate transactions often make emotional decisions. Don't be surprised if the seller pulls out rather than coming back with a counter offer. They may be feeling nervous themselves and decide not to move at all, particularly if they were planning to move to a more expensive house. Either way you are likely to delay the transaction. Bank underwriting standards may change while you are negotiating the discount. They may decide you no longer qualify.

Comment: It's a win-win scenario for the OP. Either the seller lowers the price, or the seller does what you're saying and walks away, in which case OP is saved from making a disastrously bad financial investment.

Comment: If you believe you are about to make a "disastrously bad financial investment" you should pull out.  Period.

Answer (score 7):

Recession (and the related risks and uncertainties) goes both ways.

If the real estate marked drops significantly and doesn't recover quickly, you will have overpaid if you buy at the agreed price. It would indeed be reasonable to ask for a price reduction and cancel the deal if you don't get one.

If the government decides to counter the economic recession by [emitting more money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagflation) (thanks for the link, @Underminer), real estate prices will keep raising due to inflation. It would then be reasonable for the seller to raise the price now, and cancel the deal if you don't agree.

Unless the future is known *right now* with a reasonable degree of certainty, changing the price either way is groundless. Indeed, if the price of the property has already changed (as the property valuation from your bank shows), it's only fair to review the deal to the actual price.

Comment: The pandemic is unlikely to lead to a boom in the economy. Massive unemployment and business closures loom. A falling housing market is extremely likely.

Comment: @OscarBravo What about the inflation, do you rule it out?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The problem with inflation is, it increases the cost of living, diminishing everyone´s disposable income until wages have adjusted. So that means less money for down payment=> less demand, and a higher rate of foreclosures =>more offers.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I would... Inflation is a feature of a *booming* economy; too much money chasing too few goods. If it goes too high, it can erode market confidence and lead to a recession - which leads to deflation! Capitalism has within it the seeds of its own destruction...

Comment: Tying a recession and governments emitting more money to rising house prices is wrong. Real estates prices fell in every recession dating back to at least the great depression. Saying changing the price is groundless because the future is not known also isn't accurate. The future isn't known, but stock markets around the world are down ~20% YTD. Why?

Comment: @WittyID agreed completely. The US is looking at great depression levels of economic calamity.  Any stimulus passed will be lucky to limit the damage, the idea that real estate will boom during this is... Not realistic

Comment: @OscarBravo Sorry, but "booming economy" and "too much money chasing too few goods" simply don't rhyme in my head. IMO the whole problem with the quarantine is that lots of people can't work and produce the goods they otherwise would, which leads to exactly "too much money chasing too few goods".

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, if people in quarantine can't work to earn money, how do they get the "too much money" or even leave their homes to "chase too few goods". Maybe you could make an argument for staple foods inflation because that's all people are buying...and maybe toilet-paper (lol), but in the broad based economy, inflation during a recession is very hard to come by. Check out the US and Ireland 2009 inflation - here  https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FPCPITOTLZGUSA and here https://tradingeconomics.com/ireland/inflation-cpi

Comment: Backing up Dmitry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagflation or recession-inflation can occur when the government creates policies that harm industry (lock-down) while growing the money supply too quickly (stimulus money).  Not saying it's going to happen, but it's possible.

Comment: @Underminer I appreciate you pointing out the phenomenon. However, although a lot of very smart people are very comfortable throwing the term stagflation about, I disagree. The 70's produced a very unique set of circumstances that are far from what we're experiencing today. Stagflation requires supply destruction which came in the form of OPEC with regards to a very key economic input (oil) that has very broad implications on consumer and production prices. With COVID-19, we have both supply and demand destruction, hence the argument for inflation is pinned solely on govt printing money

Comment: A careful review of the current "stimulus" bill reveals that what we call "stimulus" is actually more like a distress bridge loan. Most of the money being put into circulation (in people account for example) are simply replacing money that should have been there if they were working. Furthermore, they're replacing rent and daily essentials that are not additive to the pre-COVID state of the economy. Finally, stagflation requires a stagnant economy. With projected 10-30% drop in US Q2 GDP, the economy is anything but stagnant and oil prices today are deflationary rather than inflationary.

Comment: This answer is correct in that we can't predict whether the markets will suffer further losses, or whether they will recover and rise. But it misses an essential point: we *do* know that the markets have gone down between when OP made his offer, and now. OP can avoid *that* loss, even though he can't predict what his future loss/gain might be. If I offer you an item for £100 and in the meantime its value goes down to £80, you don't know if it will drop even more to £60, or recover to £100. But you *do* know that if you give me £100 you are overpaying by £20 today.

Comment: Will leave this article here - https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/12/economy/consumer-prices-april/index.html - to back up previous arguments i made against the likelihood of inflation or a recession inflation

Comment: In hindsight it looks like walking away from the deal would have been a bad idea!

Comment: @WittyID "if people in quarantine can't work to earn money, how do they get the too much money or even leave their homes to chase too few goods." - In some countries people got "economic relief money" which may be backed by real goods or not. The latter case (money not backed by goods) is exactly how inflation appears.

Comment: @JBentley I fully agree with your comment, though I didn't see any hint in the question that the markets have already gone down, not until the edit about the property valuation by the bank which came after the the answer was written.

Answer (score 5):

If you can still walk away from the deal, particularly without having paid any deposit, your leverage is a willingness to cancel the deal. In the US you usually only risk deposit money until you have a deed and mortgage. Are you sincerely concerned enough about the housing market changing that you will cancel the deal?

Supposing you are actually seriously considering walking away and would feel more comfortable doing so without a price change, it is reasonable to attempt negotiation before canceling. Both potential outcomes are favorable, either lower price or canceled deal. Searching for comps with decreased prices or having some market data would help!

Alternatively, if you are not willing to walk away, threatening to do so is a bluff. They might believe you, or cut the price just to make the deal happen, but they also might not. In this scenario you are not guaranteed a favorable outcome, they might rescind whatever deal they have already made with you and search for a new buyer... a pretty big gamble if you seriously want the property.

Comment: +1. The power to negotiate is the power to walk away.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are buying a house, you will have been watching closely the housing market recently. Go back and look at some of the other properties you considered that are still unsold. Has their asking price gone up or down?

The housing market is entirely capitalist so have no shame in following the fundamental capitalist ethos of supply and demand. If demand drops, so must prices. Drop your price to the lowest the seller will accept.

This may seem harsh on the seller, but that is just his luck. If gold had been discovered in the hills behind the house, he would be putting up the price accordingly. So what if he might get a few thousand less than he hoped for; you have your own family and finances to worry about and that is your first priority.

Comment: If I’m the seller, and the buyer wants to reduce the price at the last second, I make a counter offer at a higher price. And they can take it or f*** off.

Comment: @gnasher729 In that case you'd be letting your emotions get in the way of a business decision. If you don't have another buyer, you could be in trouble with this approach.

Comment: Oscar Bravo: You are underestimating me. You are confusing “emotions” with “display of emotions”. I like playing with people. Chances are he’s coming back with the tail between his legs. And my finances are such that _nothing_ can get me into trouble.

Comment: @gnasher729 I wasn't meaning you personally - I meant the-guy-who-would-do-what-you-said-you-would-do, but which you meant it as a ruse? I didn't get that nuance. The point I'm making is that you have to be Spock when it comes to business. Or at least Tessio, out of the GodFather, "Tell, Michael it was only business..."

Comment: If a house isn't selling, it would be unusual for the seller to *raise* the asking price - if no one wants it for $X, why would anyone want it for $X+Y? The price of a house that's been on the market awhile normally tends downward, so it doesn't seem like a good metric for where the real estate market as a whole is going. If someone does raise their asking price, it's likely because they priced too low in the first place, rather than a sudden improvement in economic outlook.

Comment: @gnasher729 - a bold decision! But you could be left with no buyer (suits you in principle) but also with the hassle of finding another buyer. Being rich means you can afford to do this. Few are in your seemingly fortunate position, and that must include OP..

Comment: Tim, it’s all about negotiating. If we agreed on $300,000 and suddenly you want to pay only $250,000, then I’ll tell you in the boldest way possible that this isn’t going to happen.

Comment: Great point @OscarBravo! It's unfortunate for the seller but it would be naive to pay the price of a competitive market that has just hit recession.
@gnasher729 I understand you have empathy for the seller. But this is a world level recession, it's nobody's fault. At least no body from these 2 parties.

Comment: @gnasher729 The problem with negotiating power is that when the price of your product has crashed, you don't have any. If you went back to your hypothetical buyer *today* with $350,000 it's going to be him telling you to f*** off, not the other way around. Your strategy works fine in a seller's market. It is worthless in a buyer's market.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the deal isn't legally binding, there's nothing to be lost by asking, and plenty to be gained. It may well be that the seller will say no, but at this late stage, having gone through the hoops etc. already, he may well be available for *some* negotiation.If not, then the price should stand, and if you're still happy, continue with the deal.

That deal could collapse at any time prior to final signing - I pulled out of one (selling) deal on the day of signing, having realised the house I was buying was owned by a bankrupt. Not a nice move, but perfectly legal.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what country this happened in. In the UK the only way that could happen is if you attempted to do your own legal work and botched it, or your solicitor was totally incompetent. The fact that the seller is bankrupt would be revealed by searches conducted at a fairly early stage, and certainly way earlier than the day of signing.

Comment: @JBentley - it was UK, and about 45 yrs ago.I found out several days before I was to sell my house, that the seller of the house I was buying was a bankrupt. Thus, I pulled out of both deals.

Answer (score 0):

It would be foolish to purchase the house at the price agreed at the height of the market as you might lose £100,000 or more. It's difficult to see the seller agreeing to a £100,000 discount as the future is hard to see, so why not offer £50,000 less and go ahead?

Another thing is, are you likely still to have a job in a few months and be able to afford mortgage payments? With Brexit and now the virus, the best thing would be to invest in a shack in the woods, lots of cans of baked beans and a shotgun.

Comment: Not that good an idea. It's an ill wind...

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're not telling us is: how much do you need or want to do this transaction?

People who need to move are (always) in a far weaker position than those who aren't particularly bothered, who are cool, laid back, etc. There can be reasons for being laid back. Sometimes the reasons can be wrong.

The same argument applies to sellers: do you know whether this seller really needs to sell soon, or not? Selling property is one of the most stressful experiences known to humankind, unless you happen to be someone who is sitting on a vast portfolio of properties, or is otherwise minted big time.

To summarise: you're really asking "how long is a piece of string". I don't know.

Think about this: Coronavirus could well be "over" in 8 weeks. By this, I mean that everyone everywhere will be wearing masks wherever they go, older and vulnerable people the world over will be subject to extreme protective and isolating measures until such time as a vaccine is developed. What every country in the Developed world is waiting for is for the peak to flatten, so that its health service doesn't become overwhelmed with thousands dying horrible deaths in hospital corridors.

Nothing about the present situation implies necessarily that house prices, in Ireland or anywhere else, will drop. Even a bit. It would be foolish in the extreme to assume that. **Particularly if you yourself want or need to move**.

Answer (score -3):

You are talking about a recession due to extraordinary circumstances where the financial institutions feel it appropriate to counter the recession by printing more money, while the production at a stillstand will not provide an equivalent in available goods.

That means the money will go *down* in value compared to real estate.

If you threaten to drop out of the deal right now, chances are that exactly that will happen and you'll be left with money that will lose value way faster than the usual inflation rate, and most certainly faster than the real estate you are talking about.

Comment: This is just wrong. You're essentially saying that in a recession, it is better to hold assets than it is to hold cash. In the last recession, real estate values went down by about a third in most large cities, while inflation was in the low single digits to negative. If you're predicting hyperinflation, then you're correct but that is definitely an oulier as far as economic predictions go. Fin institutions have been printing money and carrying out extraordinary QE for 10yrs now while managing to keep inflation in check.